# MinGW c++ compiler zlib1.dll missing error?

Tags: c++, compilation, mingw

I have just started to learn C++ for school, and I'm trying to download the compiler MinGW to compile my source code. However, every time I try to compile a program an error message shows up saying that `zlib1.dll` is missing.

This is the error message

> the program can't start because zlib1.dll is missing from your computer

I have tried installing/re-installing with no luck. I don't know what's the problem here?

Can anyone please help me with this problem as I have some homework that I need to do but I can't without the compiler.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you obtain the compiler from?

Comment: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started

Comment: Are there any zlib* dlls in the installation?

Comment: there is only one called zlib.dll in the following path "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\lib\perl5\vendor_perl\5.8\msys\auto\Compress\Raw\Zlib"

Comment: Seems to a post install step of some sort, check the answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [MinGW getting started](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/getting_started); an automated GUI installer assistant, or use *mingw-get*, is available (installed as "MinGW Installation Manager") and can be used to install additional libraries and manage dependencies. For the missing zlib libraries, add the mingw32-libz libraries as required.

---

It seems to have been an issue previously here on [super user](https://superuser.com/q/789397/361375). It seems you may be able to get them directly from the [zlib website](http://www.zlib.net/). [Open Babel](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Install_(MinGW)) has some info on it being required to be copied afterwards (together with some other dlls).

---

Alternatives include using the **mingw-w64 distros** from [nuwen](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) or [mingw-builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/). I've never had any issue getting these up and going. They also support x64 builds.

Comment: Thanks, that'll do for now.

Comment: Just an fyi for anyone who doesn't know where to put the dll, it's /MinGW/bin/

Answer (score 52):

I had this same problem, but fixed it like this:

1. I ran the `MinGW Installation Manager` (e.g. `C:\MinGW\libexec\mingw-get\guimain.exe`).
2. I navigated to `All Packages -> MinGW -> MinGW Libraries`.
3. I checked the boxes next to `mingw32-libz` (`dev` & `dll`).

   [image: Screenshot]
4. I went to `Installation -> Apply Changes`.

Now everything worked properly.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Shame the latest version still doesn't work with std::stoi, though.

Comment: libz is also included if you install mingw32-base (under MinGW > MinGW Base System)

Answer (score 8):

Had same problem here, I've just used `mingw-get install mingw32-libz`at the cmd and it worked.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer and/or combined with the graphical user interface answer by Doug.