# dev-c++ debuging error (gdb32.exe error)

Tags: gdb, dev-c++

When I try to debug in dev-c++ the following error message is shown:

> "I could not find a zlib1.dll"and next Emerges Messages "gdb32.exe
>   has stopped working".

I click the gdb,gdb32,gdbsever Emerges Error Messages

Note my operating system is Windows Vista.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think your error is linked with MinGW. This post might be useful :
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542055/mingw-c-compiler-zlib1-dll-missing-error